# Ignore JUnit tests if variable value is null

Tags: java, junit, junit4

I have a JUnit test class which runs 15 tests. 5 of the tests are optional in that I only wish to run them if a particular variable gets initialized by an argument. If the variable value is null I'd like to ignore these tests. Is this possible and if so, how?

Comment: if ( notInitialized ) { assert(true); return; } but what is the point of such a test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach 1:**

You can use [JUnit-ext](https://code.google.com/archive/p/junit-ext/). It has `RunIf` annotation that performs conditional tests, like:

```
@Test
@RunIf(DatabaseIsConnected.class)
public void calculateTotalSalary() {
    //your code there
}

class DatabaseIsConnected implements Checker {
   public boolean satisify() {
        return Database.connect() != null;
   }
}
```

**Approach 2**

Another approach is to use `Assume`. You can do it in a `@Before` method or in the test itself, but not in an `@After` method. If you do it in the test itself, your `@Before` method will get run. You can also do it within `@BeforeClass` to prevent class initialization. For example:

```
 @Before
 public void beforeMethod() {
     org.junit.Assume.assumeTrue(someCondition());

 }
```

**Approach 3**

I think an another option for you may be to create an annotation to denote that the test needs to meet your custom criteria, then extend the default runner with your own and using reflection, base your decision on the custom criteria. It may look something like this:

```
    public class CustomRunner extends BlockJUnit4ClassRunner {
    public CTRunner(Class<?> klass) throws initializationError {
        super(klass);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isIgnored(FrameworkMethod child) {
        if(shouldIgnore()) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.isIgnored(child);
    }

    private boolean shouldIgnore(class) {
        /* some custom criteria */
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Kaushal28. I went with Approach 2.

Answer (score 3):

You could use JUnit4's [`Assume`](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Assumptions-with-assume) feature ...

> It's good to be able to run a test against the code as it is currently written, implicit assumptions and all, or to write a test that exposes a known bug. For these situations, JUnit now includes the ability to express "assumptions"

For example:

```
 @Before
 public void setUp() {
     org.junit.Assume.assumeTrue(yourCondition());
     // ...
 }
```

If `yourCondition()` does not return true then the test for which `@Before` is running will not be executed.

Comment: Thanks @glytching. In this case  wanted most of the tests to run regardless of the variable value so went for Approach 2 below.